# Predicting values using linear regression

Tags: r, regression

I am very new to statistical analysis and R. Recently I worked on a simple linear regression model to predict values. For example: consider the below data set

```
Col A    Col B
1         10
2         16
3         67
4         ?
5         ?
```

For such data i was able to predict the values using `lm` and `predict` functions in R.

Now, suppose I am given the below data set:

```
inventory  jan-sales   feb-sales   mar-sales   apr-sales  may-sales
12         4           0           2           ?          ?
190        54          67          89          ?          ? 
123        67          22          11          ?          ? 
654       167          100        300          ?          ?
789       567          10         80           ?          ? 
543       223          221        0            ?          ?
```

In this data set, each line has total available units of a particular item and how many of those items were sold on each month. Now based on this data if I am asked to predict how many will be sold in the months of April and May, how do I use R and Linear regression or multiple linear regression to predict sales for April and May?

Comment: Show us how you were able to predict the values using `lm` and `predict` for the first data set and what you tried for the second. I believe that you were indeed able to predict the values (because you quoted those functions), but it's unclear what you've tried for the second one too.

Comment: That depends on what you think drives sales in particular months (i.e. what are the predictors?). Three months worth of sales are not going to be enough to detect any trend or cyclical pattern in the data, so you would either need longer time series, or have some data at hand describing sensible predictors.

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your own question with wrong formating

Comment: @David my guess is the OP has the Q in a text editor, corrected the dataset and changed "April and May" to "March and April", and pasted the whole incorrectly formatted slab in again. To the OP - if people fix up your formatting and you want to make changes, please only edit what needs to be changed.

Comment: Firstly thank you David for editing my question. I had images but was not allowed to post them.

Comment: This is just sample data, I HAVE DATA WHICH HAS SALES FOR EVERY MONTH IN A YEAR. For the first data set it was simple, values of COLB depend on COLA so I used lm(COLB ~ COLA), this gave me the y intercept and slope. I can use those to calculate the values for 4, 5 manually or use predict function in R. But for the 2nd data set I am not even sure how to proceed.

Comment: Post a link to that image, we will post it for you

Comment: @jbaums I have a larger dataset which has sales data for lot more months. This one is just a sample

Comment: [stats.se] might be a better fit for this question, since it's asking what type of model to fit to these data.